# Bash set -u allow single unbound variable

Tags: bash, variables

With bash, you can allow `set -e` to fail a specific command like:

```
someCommandThatProbablyFails || true
```

Is there anything for `set -u` to allow a specific variable to be unbound?

Specifically I'm doing something like:

```
if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
    SOMEVAR="${1}"
else
    SOME_STUFF_TO_DETERMINE_SOMEVAR
fi
```

In this case, it's `"${1}"` that triggers the unbound variable error if nothing was passed into the script from the command line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an empty string as the [default](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for an unset variable like this:

```
${POSSIBLY_UNSET_VARIABLE-}
```

Comment: Should this work even if the expected empty variable is a cmd line parameter, ie: `"${1}"`?

Comment: Why don't you try it and report back?

Comment: I'm afraid it will over-ride whatever was passed in if there was a value. I'm doing something like: `if [ -n "${1}" ]; then SOMEVAR="${1}" else DO_SOME_STUFF_TO_DETERMINE_SOMEVAR; fi`, ie: it's `"${1}"` that's triggering the unbound variable error.

Comment: It should work fine--`test -n` checks for the empty string, which `${1-}` would give you.